# How to create new objects based on user input?

Tags: java, object, arraylist

I am not sure what the proper terminology for this is but, I am trying to figure out how I could create new instances of an object based on a users input.

Let's say I have 5 different classes of object and I will only need a total of 5 objects from all or some of the classes, I might have more than 1 of a certain class and none of another. what could I write that would create a new instance of all or some of these objects?

Furthermore, I would need to have the new objects fields be set to specific parameters without the users input and I would need to have an `ArrayList` created at the same time.

Here is an example of 1 such object and arraylist I might need to be generated based on user input with these exact fields:

```
ArrayList<Item> rangerInv0 = new ArrayList<Item>();    
Ranger rangerObj0 = new Ranger("Ranger", 100, 4, 10, rangerInv0);
```

Is there a way I could do this? What would this be called?

Also, I am looking to avoid a situation like this

```
if (resp == 1){
  if (rangerCount == 0){
      ArrayList<Item> rangerInv0 = new ArrayList<Item>();    
      Ranger rangerObj0 = new Ranger("Ranger", 100, 4, 10, rangerInv0);

      rangerObj0.pickUp(mh1000);
      rangerObj0.pickUp(s1000);
      rangerObj0.pickUp(t1000);

      rangerObj0.equip(mh1000);
      rangerObj0.equip(s1000);
      rangerObj0.equip(t1000);

      playerUnits.add(rangerObj0);
      playerUnitsCount++;
      rangerCount++;
      }
      else if (rangerCount == 1){
      ArrayList<Item> rangerInv1 = new ArrayList<Item>();    
      Ranger rangerObj1 = new Ranger("Ranger", 100, 4, 10, rangerInv1);

      rangerObj1.pickUp(mh1000);
      rangerObj1.pickUp(s1000);
      rangerObj1.pickUp(t1000);

      rangerObj1.equip(mh1000);
      rangerObj1.equip(s1000);
      rangerObj1.equip(t1000);

      playerUnits.add(rangerObj1);
      playerUnitsCount++;
      rangerCount++;
      }
      else if (rangerCount == 2){
      ArrayList<Item> rangerInv2 = new ArrayList<Item>();    
      Ranger rangerObj2 = new Ranger("Ranger", 100, 4, 10, rangerInv2);

      rangerObj2.pickUp(mh1000);
      rangerObj2.pickUp(s1000);
      rangerObj2.pickUp(t1000);

      rangerObj2.equip(mh1000);
      rangerObj2.equip(s1000);
      rangerObj2.equip(t1000);

      playerUnits.add(rangerObj2);
      playerUnitsCount++;
      rangerCount++;
      }
    }
```

is there a way I could update my object and ArrayList names via variables or some kind of counter?

it would be cool if I could do something like this but so far I cannot find a way to make this work:

```
int rangerCount = 0;
String rangerInvNum = ("rangerInv" + rangerCount);
String rangerObjNum = ("rangerObj" + rangerCount);

ArrayList<Item> rangerInvNum = new ArrayList<Item>();    
Ranger rangerObjNum = new Ranger("Ranger", 100, 4, 10, rangerInvNum);
```

Comment: It looks like you need to look into constructors

Comment: Yep. You have to first of all learn how to use fields and constructors together. And note: from a design point of view, you shouldnt pass a list of items to your Ranger. Because that allows other code to *change* the data within your ranger. Any piece of code that knows that list object can modify the list! Thus: consider to give the Ranger a method "addItem()" and "removeItem()" ... but dont expose that internal data structure to the world!

Comment: I am passing objects to my arraylist, can I do that with a list?

Answer (score 0):

What you need is to use proper design pattern for this kind of logic and what you can to choose here seems to be [Builder](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Builder_pattern), [Factory](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Factory_method_pattern) or [Strategy](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Strategy_pattern) (the last one in this case would be kind of factory actually)

The simpliest solution like this would look like

```
public interface Item {}

public class Ranger implements Item {
    // ...
}

// ...

public class CommonCreationProperties {
    // All the fields user can popularne
}

public class ItemFactory{
    public Item createItem(CommonProperties properties)
        if(isRanger(properties)) {
            return new Ranger(properties.getType(), ...); // Event better introduce builder here
        } else if(is...) {
             return ...
        }
    }

    private boolean isRanger(CommonProperties properties) {
        return "Ranger".equals(properties.getType());
    }

    // ...
}
```

Of course providing some special `type` field to recognize what type of `Item` user provided is one of the options - you can implement some another mechanism - the only thing is that using such approach your items should have some common interface like `Item` and many implementations depends on what types of items you need

Answer (score 0):

You could try a switch case:

```
String className = "user input here"
switch(className) {
  case "Ranger": {
    Ranger myRanger = new Ranger();
    ArrayList<Item> rangerInv0 = new ArrayList<Item>();
    break;
    }
  case "otherClass": {
    OtherClass myObj = new OtherClass();
    ArrayList<Item> otherClassInv0 = new ArrayList<Item>();
    break;
    }
case "....": {
    // ....
    break;
    }
  default: {
    // print error message, end program, ...
    }
}
```

Comment: I get what you are saying, please see my edited code with my if statements and see if this could be simplified

Answer (score 0):

- This will help to you
- you don't need to create Object types and One by one variables and you can
  use some generics like I have implemented

```
public class Ranger<E> {

    private  String objectName;
    private Type val1;
    private Type val2;
    private Type val3; // here you can set any kind of typs ex, int,string 
    private E[] rangerInv0; // you can set any kind of array 

    public Ranger(String objectName, Type val1, Type val2, Type val3, E[] rangerInv0) {
        super();
        this.objectName = objectName;
        this.val1 = val1;
        this.val2 = val2;
        this.val3 = val3;
        this.rangerInv0 = rangerInv0;
    }
```